# chrome.storage.set. non-persistent behavior along with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, cookies

I have the following code, that is an attempt to make chrome.cookie.set execute consequently for numerous values.

**TLDR:**
the problem itself is that the value passed to the set function of the chrome.cookies API differs from the value received in the callback, and actually saved.

It works, but the that are saved are incorrect:

```
angular.module('setupApp')
  .service('cookieService', function($rootScope, $timeout, COOKIE_CONF) {
    var cookieKeys = COOKIE_CONF.boolKeys.concat(COOKIE_CONF.numericKeys);
    return {
        get: syncWebApp,
        set: function(obj){
            var val = null;
            var queue = [];
            for(var _key in obj){
                if(cookieKeys.indexOf(_key) !== -1){
                    if(COOKIE_CONF.numericKeys.indexOf(_key) !== -1 && typeof obj[_key] !== 'undefined'){
                        val =  obj[_key] + "";
                    }
                    else{
                        val =  obj[_key] + "";

                        if(obj[_key] == "true"){
                            obj[_key] = "1";
                        }
                        else if(obj[_key] == "false"){
                            obj[_key] = "0";
                        }
                        val = !!obj[_key] && obj[_key] != '0' ? "1" : "0";
                    }
                    queue.push({"value": val, "key": _key});
                }
            }

            function saveNext(_key, val){
                queue.shift();
                chrome.cookies.set({
                        "url": COOKIE_CONF.options.domain,
                        "path": COOKIE_CONF.options.path,
                        "name": _key,
                        "value": val
                    },
                    function(data) {
                        console.log({save_key: data.name, saved_value: data.value + ''});
                        if(!data){
                            console.log(chrome.extension.lastError);
                            console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);
                        }
                        if(queue && queue[0]){
                            console.log(queue[0]);
                            saveNext(queue[0].key, queue[0].value)
                        }

                    });
            }
            if(queue && queue[0]){
                console.log(queue[0]);
                $timeout(function(){
                    $rootScope.$apply(function(){
                        saveNext(queue[0].key, queue[0].value)
                    });
                }, 0);


            }
        }
    }
  });
```

The following is logged out, which is very odd:

```
Object {save_key: "age", saved_value: "81"} cookieservice.js:74
Object {value: "false", key: "anemic_tendency"} cookieservice.js:80
Object {save_key: "age", saved_value: "81"} cookieservice.js:74
Object {value: "false", key: "anemic_tendency"} cookieservice.js:80
Object {save_key: "anemic_tendency", saved_value: "0"} cookieservice.js:74
Object {value: "500", key: "blood_test"} cookieservice.js:80
Object {save_key: "anemic_tendency", saved_value: "0"} cookieservice.js:74
Object {value: "500", key: "blood_test"} cookieservice.js:80
Object {save_key: "blood_test", saved_value: "500"} cookieservice.js:74
Object {value: "false", key: "celiac"} cookieservice.js:80
Object {save_key: "blood_test", saved_value: "500"} cookieservice.js:74
Object {value: "false", key: "celiac"} cookieservice.js:80
Object {save_key: "celiac", saved_value: "0"} cookieservice.js:74
Object {value: "false", key: "chrones_disease"} cookieservice.js:80
Object {save_key: "celiac", saved_value: "0"} cookieservice.js:74
Object {value: "false", key: "chrones_disease"} cookieservice.js:80
Object {save_key: "chrones_disease", saved_value: "0"} cookieservice.js:74
Object {value: "false", key: "contraceptives"} cookieservice.js:80
Object {save_key: "chrones_disease", saved_value: "0"} cookieservice.js:74
Object {value: "false", key: "contraceptives"} cookieservice.js:80
Object {save_key: "contraceptives", saved_value: "0"} cookieservice.js:74
Object {value: "false", key: "easily_bruised"} cookieservice.js:80
Object {save_key: "contraceptives", saved_value: "0"} cookieservice.js:74
Object {value: "false", key: "easily_bruised"} cookieservice.js:80
Object {save_key: "easily_bruised", saved_value: "0"} cookieservice.js:74
Object {value: "false", key: "healthGoalsCheckbox"} cookieservice.js:80
Object {save_key: "easily_bruised", saved_value: "0"} cookieservice.js:74
Object {value: "false", key: "healthGoalsCheckbox"} cookieservice.js:80
Object {save_key: "healthGoalsCheckbox", saved_value: "0"} cookieservice.js:74
Object {value: "0", key: "male"} cookieservice.js:80
Object {save_key: "healthGoalsCheckbox", saved_value: "0"} cookieservice.js:74
Object {value: "0", key: "male"} cookieservice.js:80
Object {save_key: "male", saved_value: "1"} cookieservice.js:74
Object {value: "false", key: "mthf"} cookieservice.js:80
Object {save_key: "male", saved_value: "1"} cookieservice.js:74
Object {value: "false", key: "mthf"} cookieservice.js:80
Object {save_key: "mthf", saved_value: "false"} cookieservice.js:74
Object {value: "8", key: "pg"} cookieservice.js:80
Object {save_key: "mthf", saved_value: "false"} cookieservice.js:74
Object {value: "8", key: "pg"} cookieservice.js:80
Object {save_key: "pg", saved_value: "0"} cookieservice.js:74
Object {value: "0", key: "pregnancy"} cookieservice.js:80
Object {save_key: "pg", saved_value: "0"} cookieservice.js:74
Object {value: "0", key: "pregnancy"} cookieservice.js:80
Object {save_key: "pregnancy", saved_value: "0"} cookieservice.js:74
Object {value: "1", key: "rda"} cookieservice.js:80
Object {save_key: "pregnancy", saved_value: "0"} cookieservice.js:74
Object {value: "1", key: "rda"} cookieservice.js:80
Object {save_key: "rda", saved_value: "1"} cookieservice.js:74
Object {value: "1", key: "vegetarian"} cookieservice.js:80
Object {save_key: "rda", saved_value: "1"} cookieservice.js:74
Object {value: "1", key: "vegetarian"} cookieservice.js:80
Object {save_key: "vegetarian", saved_value: "0"} cookieservice.js:74
Object {save_key: "vegetarian", saved_value: "0"}
```

Tried debugging, canceling the recursion, and numerous other stuff, but ended up clueless, please assist me with this.

Comment: I have no idea what you actually want. Why is that wrong? What are you expecting to see?

Comment: Object {value: "1", key: "vegetarian"} cookieservice.js:80
Object {save_key: "vegetarian", saved_value: "0"} cookieservice.js:74,
the saved value differs from the actual value, wtf?!